(Flutter Web) Trying to stream data on Firebase Realtime Database REST API
I was trying to code my own API logic using RTDB Rest API. So don't recommend me to use firebase_database package!
The stream work great on dart console, mobile, desktop but when i debug on web, it stuck when i send request. Here my code:
  Future<Stream<DatabaseEvent>> getStream() async {
    final request = http.Request('GET', uri);
    request.headers['Accept'] = 'text/event-stream';
    final response = await request.send(); // Stuck here
    return response.stream
        .transform(utf8.decoder)
        .map((event) => DatabaseEvent.fromString(event));
  }

Firebase docs.
